# Converting a string sent via SMS into RSA Public/Private key in android

Tags: android, encryption

I've been working on it for several days but without success, I' m doing SMS encryption in android using RSA encryption, the problem is how can I convert a String to public key and use it for encryption, I'm sending the publicKey converted into String via SMS but I'm not able to get the key back.

This is how my algorithm works but when I send "puk" as a string via Sms and make encryption it doesn't work anymore!!! plz help me . . .

```
private final static String RSA = "RSA";
public static PublicKey uk;
public static PrivateKey rk;
public static String puk;

public static void generateKey() throws Exception
{
 KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);
 gen.initialize(128, new SecureRandom());
 KeyPair keyPair = gen.generateKeyPair();
 uk = keyPair.getPublic();
 rk = keyPair.getPrivate();
 puk = uk.toString();
}

private static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey pubRSA) throws Exception
{
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubRSA);
 return cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
}

public final static String encrypt(String text)
{
 try {
  return byte2hex(encrypt(text, uk));
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return null;
}

public final static String decrypt(String data)
{
 try{
  String text =  new String(decrypt(hex2byte(data.getBytes())));
  return text+" OK";
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     return "Error: "+e;
 }

}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] src) throws Exception
{
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rk);
 return cipher.doFinal(src);
}
public static String byte2hex(byte[] b)
{
 String hs = "";
 String stmp = "";
 for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n ++)
 {
  stmp = Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 0xFF);
  if (stmp.length() == 1)
   hs += ("0" + stmp);
  else
   hs += stmp;
 }
 return hs.toUpperCase();
}

public static byte[] hex2byte(byte[] b)
{
 if ((b.length % 2) != 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello");

 byte[] b2 = new byte[b.length / 2];

 for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n += 2)
 {
  String item = new String(b, n, 2);
  b2[n/2] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(item, 16);
 }
 return b2;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not make for a valid stackoverflow question.